# Does the original thread execute one of the program segments defined by the `omp section` directives?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, openmp

When program execution reaches a `omp sections` directive, program segments defined by the following `omp section` directive are distributed for parallel execution among available threads.

- Is the original thread, i.e. the thread which runs before reaching `omp sections`, one of the threads that execute one of the program segments defined by the `omp section` directives?
- after all the threads finish executing their program segments defined by `omp section` directives, will the original thread be the only one which remains existing and continue execution?

In the following example, which thread is the original thread, 1 or 2 or something else?

```
#pragma omp sections
{

    # pragma omp section
    { printf("thread 1 here\n"); }
    # pragma omp section
    { printf("thread 2 here\n"); }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example is incomplete. Let's complete it naively.

```
int main()
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        { printf("thread 1 here\n"); }
        # pragma omp section
        {printf("thread 2 here\n"); }
    }
}
```

There is only a single thread here. `#pragma omp section` alone creates no additional threads.

You use `sections` within a parallel construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp sections
```

Which is equivalent to

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
```

The `parallel` construct creates a team of threads. All threads run until the `sections` construct, wherein each `section` block will be executed by one of the threads in the team.

Talking about threads entering / leaving a parallel section:

- Yes, the thread that encounters the `parallel` construct will become part of the team running. In fact it will become it's master thread with the thread number `0`. It will participate in the execution of sections if the team runs into a `sections` construct. It is however not guaranteed that it will execute any section, there may not even be enough sections for all threads. The scheduling method from section to thread within a team is implementation defined.
- Yes, after the end of a `parallel` region, the original thread is the (only) one that will continue the execution of the outer code.

Comment: Thanks. How do you get the thread id number of the current thread?

Comment: Is there some sort of OpenMP knob to twist to "encourage" the master to run one of the sections?  It's less than optimal that the master thread would be suspended (and voluntarily abandon its CPU slice) to let worker threads run each section, since the master does a join at the end of the parallel block

Comment: All threads join at the end of a parallel section. Don't worry about it unless you have evidence that there is an actual issue.